# show hide column grid ionic if change size device

Tags: grid, ionic4

I have two column in grid ionic with different size :

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="7">
    <div>
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="5">
    <div>
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

if handphone size show column number two only, if pad's size show two column.
how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify the number of the columns it will take whatever is left on the screen. `class="ion-hide-sm-up"` will hide element that is bigger than mobile device.

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="7" class="ion-hide-sm-up">
    <div>
      1 of 2
    </div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <div>
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Instead of `sm` in the class you can use `md`, `lg`, `xl` and instead of `up` you can use `down` depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much @ACES This is not mentioned on the ionic grid system documentations page. However, your answer helped me to find this https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#responsive-display-attributes

Comment: Super helpful. This is great to hide/show content based on sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Media Querys: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp - like that you can apply styles for device sizes, specified by you.